# How to s3-select all data within inner array of parquet file

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I have parquet files on s3 which need to be queried using S3 Select. The parquet files are generated from JSON files with inner arrays. The S3 Select query can get the first array but if i tried to query the records in the inner array it fails to return the ids. Saying its an invalid data source

What I tried:

```
Looking up documentation on Amazon proves no use
Multiple formats of the s3 select query
```

Json Structure

```
  {
     "Array": [
        {
          "Id": "1"
        },
        {
          "Id": "2"
        }
     ]
   }
```

Query

```
  select s.Array[*].id from s3object s
```

Expect to get all the ids back from the query so should return Id 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

`select  s.Id from  S3Object[*].Array[*]  s limit 5`  will return all the ID's in the Array.